# Strange message boxes started to appear on my Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-10

The following message boxes started to appear on my Windows 10 machine:

[image]

They are displayed periodically and stay open until I close them.

How to determine what process or app does this?

What `Verify Sig Error` is?

Comment: Are you using uTorrent? If so, uninstall it and switch to qbittorrent or deluge.

Comment: Just expanding on @Gantendo comment: 1. Error: see https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/88416-error-verify-sig-error-0x800b010c/ 2. uTorrent issues: see https://www.top10vpn.com/guides/is-utorrent-safe/ . 3. Alternatives: https://www.techradar.com/best/torrent-client

Comment: "Sig Error: 0x800b0003" error code 0x800b0003 indicates that there is a problem with the digital signature of a file or a driver, which can lead to the installation failure of the software. There is a possibility that your computer is infected, so I suggest to use your installed antivirus to run deep checks and also run [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Comment: @Gantendo yes, it was uTorrent.